# "in" operator not working as expected?(python)

Tags: python, list, operators

I am a beginner at python when I was going through the operators concept. I got stuck. Can someone help me out?? Why isn't the in operator returning true??

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5] 
print(list1 in list2)`
```

Instead, it returns false.

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [1,2,3] 
print(list1 in list2)`
```

returns false in both cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`list1 in list2` doesn't check if each element of `list1` is contained in `list2`; it checks if `list1` *itself* is an element of `list2`:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3] in [1, 2, 3]
False
>>> [1, 2, 3] in [[1, 2, 3]]
True
```

You can use the `all` function to automate the element-wise check:

```
>>> all(x in list2 for x in list1)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

As Chepner said, `list1 in list2` checks if `list1` is in `list2`. What you can do, is check if each element from `list1` is in `list2` using a for loop:

```
for i in list1:
    if i in list2:
        print(i)
```

This will print out all the elements which are found in both `list1` and in `list2`.

What you can also do, which is a lot quicker answer is use `sets`.
First, make list1 and list2 into a set:

```
set_list1 = set(list1)
set_list2 = set(list2)
```

You can also write a set without starting from a list:

```
set_list1 = {1,2,3}
set_list2 = {3,4,5}
```

Notice that, in sets, you use `{}` not `[]`

Then, here are a few things you can do with sets:

```
print(set_list1 | set_list2)  # Union - {1,2,3,4,5}
print(set_list1 & set_list2)  # Intersection - {3}
print(set_list1 - set_list2)  # Difference - {1,2}
print(set_list2 - set_list1)  # Difference - {4,5}
print(set_list1 ^ set_list2)  # Symmetric difference - {1,2,4,5}
```

I hope this helped.

Comment: Using a `set` isn't automatically quicker: you still have to consider the time it takes to build the `set` in the first place. Sets also only apply when your list consists of hashable elements.